# Convert strings into number values within subarrays

Tags: ruby

My goal is to convert letters within words in an array into their corresponding number values so that:

```
["I", "like", "elephants"]
```

turns into

```
[[18], [21, 18, 20, 14], [14, 21, 14, 25, 17, 10, 23, 29, 28]]
```

How can I attain my goal?

This is my current code:

```
words = ["I", "like", "elephants"]
seperate_words = []
converted_words = []

words.each do |word|
  seperate_words.push(word.split(//))
end
puts seperate_words.to_s

seperate_words.each do |word|
  word.each do |letter|
    converted_words.push(letter.to_i 36)
  end
end
puts converted_words.to_s
```

I cannot separate the words as sub-arrays; I get:

```
[18, 21, 18, 20, 14, 14, 21, 14, 25, 17, 10, 23, 29, 28]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to introduce intermediate array, where you can store the results of operation on a single word:

```
separate_words.each do |word|
  converted_word = []
  word.each do |letter|
    converted_word.push(letter.to_i(36))
  end
  converted_words.push(converted_word)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want is a transformation (map). First, I split every word in an array of characters. then, every letter of every array of character becomes an integer.

```
words = ["I", "like", "elephants"]
words.map(&:chars).map { |letters| letters.map { |letter| letter.to_i 36 } }
```

Comment: Basically what you want is a transformation. First, I split every word in an array of characters. then, every letter of every array of character becomes an integer.

Comment: That's a good one, why don't you put this explanation in answer itself?

Comment: You could also do it as such `words.map { |w| w.chars.map { |c| c.to_i(36) } }`.

Comment: Is there any way for me to use this function to do the oppsite, i.e. to convert the numbers back into letters?

Comment: That is, once I've converted them from letters to numbers, how do I convert the numbers back to letters? @Ursus

Comment: I'm not sure if there is such an opposite operation for this kind of thing you do.